# Output of awk is not shown when used after a grep command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to get CPU % of a process using `pid` from `top` command in Mac OS. When I use `top | awk '{print $3}'` I get the CPU % for all the processes. However, using `top | grep 11568 | awk '{print $3}'` returns nothing. The output of `top | grep 11568` is

```
11568  java             0.0  09:48.45 663   2   1533+  521M+  0B     741M+  11560 11560 sleeping *0[64+]       0.00000 0.00000    501 1335625+ 803+    12376+    4146+     37032037+  28783+    3748122+   514+    112576  0.0   0      0      amar               N/A    N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this command since I don't have mac os, could you please try following.

```
your_command | awk -F' +'  '/11568/{print $3}'
```

Comment: It worked, Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that as the output of `top` is continuous, thus using `-l 1` helps awk to parse the data as the data is continuously changing the output of awk is empty. Thus using `top -l 1 | grep 19275 | awk '{ print $3}'` gives the correct output. Also `top | awk -F' +'  '/11568/{print $3}'` gives the correct output, however using `top | awk -F' +'  '/11568/{print $3}'` in a shell file does not work, I want to find the average CPU consumption, so I need to assign the printed value to a variable and then find the average value